# php - Is it possible to count the number of keys in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I've googled this but found no answers, so I guess it's not possible. If there is a way, I'd love to know it. Thanks

Comment: with keys, do you mean only associative keys, e.g. those with a non-numeric index? For instance `array('foo' => 'bar, 'baz')` would return 1? Or you just want all keys?

Comment: google is your friend, but it'd better not be your *only* friend. When there is documentation available - and php has one of the best documentations I've ever read - use it.
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The number of keys in the array will always be the number of elements in the array, as the keys must be unique. So:

```
$numKeys = count($array);
```

Answer (score 13):

```
count(array_keys($array));
```

Answer (score 4):

Array is as long as its keys, you can use either of `count` or `sizeof` eg

```
echo count($your_array);
```

or

```
echo sizeof($your_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array('one', 'two', 'three');
echo count($array);
```

http://lv.php.net/count